# Esper: destroy the statement when Subscriber is firing,will the subscriber output be interrupted?

Tags: destroy, esper

I create a NamedWindow at time 'T', it fires every 5 minutes, assume Subscriber will cost 30 seconds to output all results, for example, T+5min, fire start, T + 5 min + 30 second fire finish. Here is the problem: when I destroy the statements at T + 5 min + 10 seconds, will the subscriber just output 10 seconds and the rest results of 20 seconds be destroyed? subscriber will be interrupted immediately at T + 5 min + 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Esper never uses Thread.interrupt on a subscriber or listener.